# Determining matrices for an affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Determine the matrices **A** and **b** for the affine transformation

t(**x**) = **Ax** + **b**,

where **A** and **b** are $2 \times 2$ and $2 \times 1$ matrices, respectively, given that *t* maps each point of the line $y = 0$ onto itself and $(0,1)$ onto $(2,3)$.  Prove also that *t* is a parallel projection of $\mathbb R^2$ onto itself.

Help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. I'm at a loss for where to even begin.

Comment: You are told that $t(x, 0) = (0, 0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, and that $t(0, 1) = (2, 3)$. Plug in $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ in the first condition. Then you have 6 scalar equations and 6 unknowns.

Comment: once you determine these, which I'm pretty sure I have done...how do you prove the parallel projection part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ and ${\bf b} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Your first piece of information tells you that: $t\left(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) = A{\bf x}+{\bf b} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}x+b_1 \\ a_{21}x+b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ for every $x$. Use $x=0$ and $x=1$ to figure out several $a_{ij}$'s and the $b_i$'s.

Next, you're given that $t\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = A\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} +{\bf b} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{12}+b_1 \\ a_{21}+b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Putting this together will give you your map.

Comment: @Ataraxia so a11=1, a12=2, a21=0 and a22=3. And b1=0 and b2=0. Does that seem right?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: OK - so then how exactly do you prove that it is a parallel projection? Is it simply since b is the zero vector that t(x) is a linear transformation and is thus a parallel projection?

Comment: What definition are you using for "parallel projection"?